# difference between matrics programming and image processing in matlab and octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am a beginner about the Matlab or octave programming now I am going to a project 
in which I am doing image processing .
I know that in image processing all matrices functions is implementing in image processing 
so I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I  want to know that is there any difference between matrices function in Matlab and octave.

Comment: In general allmost all comparisons will boil down to the core that matlab is a bit better overall (speed, documentation). And that octave is a free matlab clone, which will still get the job done most of the time. -- Have flagged this as too broad as both languages are about matrix calculations and a proper answer would list most differences between the languages.

Comment: This is duplicate of [differences between octave and matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084246). Since you're asking exactly about image processing, I find Octave suitable for me (I do microscope image processing) but depending on your exact needs you may disagree (specially if you require interactive usage). Also, since you're using Ubuntu 12.04, if you install the image package from Ubuntu repositories you will have a very very old version. See [how to install liboctave-dev-3.2 on ubuntu 12.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742384/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any syntactical differences when using matrices in Matlab/Octave. There are some general differences in syntax (comments, strings) that are described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Differences_between_Octave_and_MATLAB) but they don't affect the usage of matrices.

There might be differences in speed. Octave is said to be slower on loops, probably because it lacks some optimizations that Matlab does but I have never tested.

In my opinion the greatest difference between Matlab and Octave is the number and quality of available toolboxes. For your purposes you can compare the functionalities of Matlab's [image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.de/products/image/) and Octave's [image package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/). (Thanks for the link, juliohm)

Comment: [GNU Octave 3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/) is an IDE and has a debugger. There is also a [package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/) for image processing.

Comment: @juliohm Thanks for the hint. I didn't know that 3.8 has been released. Without having tested it, I cannot say which GUI is better, of course. However, I'm quite sure that Matlab's GUI is more mature.