# How compile m-file without installed Matlab?

Tags: matlab, compilation

What is the simplest way to compile m-file without installed matlab?

And can someone say when will users get possibility for compiling programs with training networks (not only using training networks in compiling)?

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB is not a *compiled* language, it is *interpreted* at runtime, so you need to have MATLAB installed to run a m-File (script). You can use the [MATLAB compiler](http://mathworks.com/products/compiler/) software to create a standalone application from an m-File or a function.

To run an m-file without having MATLAB, you can use [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). Octave is an open-source software which has almost the same syntax and functionality as MATLAB. They are not 100% identical though, so you will have to migrate your script. As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084246/differences-between-octave-and-matlab), code which runs in MATLAB will almost always run in Octave too, so it should work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

for very basic scripting you can use this online octave(/matlab) compiler I found http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/try_matlab.php There are some limitations of course, but for basic scripts it works well